# Geth diskspace outside of datadir

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I am synchronising geth using

`geth --datadir "<mounted large drive>" --fast --cache 1024 --rpc --rpcaddr <publicip> --rpcport 8545`

The `chaindata` folder in the mounted drive is increasing in size (7GB after a few hours), so I am confident that `-datadir` is working... But for some reason my home drive is filling up at about the same pace.

I don't really have any idea where the data is coming from. This is a ubuntu box only for this geth node so there are no other programs running.

Geth eventually stops with out of diskspace, not because the datadir is full but the home drive is full (it's only 25GB). There is still >100GB available on mounted external drive when it stops.

In the above command line, is there anything obvious to suggest what is putting data on the home drive? I'm not mining so it's not `.ethash`

Thanks

Comment: and did you check the .ethash size? there is no other place to store data than `--datadir` in `geth`. I think the current chain should be about half of terabyte size, so your 100Gig won't help either.

Comment: get the `PID` of `geth` process and do a `ls -l /proc/[PID_OF_GETH]/fd` , it will show you the open files. Or try `lsof` to find open files of the process

Comment: I've followed that instruction and true enough `geth` is only writing to the mounted drive. So why is it stopping saying the drive is full when it is still >90% empty

Comment: Fixed it... it works when datadir is a sub directory of the mounted drive. Not when you make the datadir the root of the mounted drive